# Get Git repository's last commit

Tags: git, githooks, git-log

I have a central Git bare repository.  When a push is made to that repo I want to run a post-receive hook.  What that hook will do is create a message on a Basecamp project (using their API).  I want info on the update that was just performed.  Right now I think `git log -2 --stat` is good enough but would like a little more info (branch that was updated, file created, files removed).  Can anyone help with the command(s) I need to do to get all the info? Performing multiple commands is fine with with me, there probably isn't a single command that will get me all the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find the latest commit by examining and sorting the files under `.git/refs/heads`: every time a new commit is made, the corresponding `refs/heads` file is changed, i.e. when committing to `master`, `refs/heads/master` is updated.

So, let's develop a solution.

**First task:** find all branches (i.e. all files under `refs/heads` and print out when they were last changed. You're talking about hooks, so we give the path relative to the `.git/hooks` directory:

```sh
find ../refs/heads -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'
```

This produces a list of all branches along with their change date. See the [man page of `find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for an explanation of the parameters.

**Second Task:** sort the obtained list

```sh
find ../refs/heads -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |\
sort
```

**Third Task:** we need the newest element in that list. Since `sort` sorts from old to new, our desired item is at the bottom of the list. Get this element with `tail` (only one item, therefore pass the `-1` flag):

```sh
find ../refs/heads -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |\
sort    |\
tail -1
```

**Fourth Task:** drop the date in the obtained line. From our `printf` statement we know that date and path are separated with a space. Feed this as delimiter into `cut` (`-d " "`) and tell it we need the second field (i.e. the file path, `-f 2`). For convenience, we'll store this file path in a variable called `$LATESTHEAD`:

```sh
LATESTHEAD=$(\
    find ../refs/heads -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |\
    sort    |\
    tail -1 |\
    cut -d ' ' -f 2 )
```

**Fifth Task:** Now we know the filename, but we need the content. This is the latest revistion that could be passed to `git log`. `cat` does the job. Store the latest revision in `$LATESTREV`

```sh
LATESTHEAD=$(\
    find ../refs/heads -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' |\
    sort    |\
    tail -1 |\
    cut -d ' ' -f 2 )
LATESTREV=$(cat $LATESTHEAD)
```

Now, you could use `$LATESTREV` to do any dirty things you want.

Perhaps not the most elegant solution (probably someone will come up and tell you a much easier one-liner) but works for me.

Comment: This actually works for well as well.  I need the branch name as well, so I guess I have to run the **Third Task** first to the branch name.  After that I run the **Fifth Task** to get the commit hash.  After that I run `git log --stat -1 <commit-hash-here>` to get the full commit info.  It's strange I have to add `-1`.  I I don't it gives me everyting...strange.  Anyways it looks like it works!  Thanks eckes!

Comment: Sorry for promoting my answer, but I cannot see why you're using find here if all the information is given on stdin by git when calling post-receive (see [githooks(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#post-receive)).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `--summary` to your git log will produce the new and deleted file listing (git refers to them as "nodes"):

```
git log --stat --summary -1
```

To get the branch, try running:

```
git branch --contains `git log --oneline -1 |cut -f1 -d\ ` |cut -b3-
```

Note: I am testing this on my mac. Unix `cut` is 1 indexed but I believe Debian `cut` is 0 indexed. If so, and if you are on a Debian box, change `-f1` to `-f0` and the branch command should work just fine

Answer (score 2):

If there is no specific reason why you use `post-receive`, I would rather suggest using `update`, which gets the old ref, the new ref and the branch as command line arguments.

So you can just get the whole log using the `git log` commands suggested here and giving `oldref..newref` as argument (replacing `oldref` and `newref` respectively).

For more information see the [githooks(5) manpage on the update hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#update). You even can abort the update at that point if you need to.

Actually, you get the same information in the `post-receive` hook on stdin. I do not see why you need to do a lot of `find` commands to accomplish that task.

Comment: How do I get the information for `oldref` and `newref`?  I'm quite new with Git and hooks.  I got my Git repo connected with my Basecamp and works like a charm.  But if there's a better way and I can get more info, even better.  I'm going to go ahead and read up on that githooks(5) manpage but if you can give a same, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Okay, I'm switching to `update` hook instead.  Thanks for the suggestion Jonas.

Comment: This works nicely. Note though you can't abort if you use the post-receive hook like you can with the update hook ([see here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive)): **This hook does not affect the outcome of git receive-pack, as it is called after the real work is done.**